# Regex get all matches in one match

Tags: php, regex

I'm searching for a regex that matches all words, but will give only one match.

What I have:

---

Regex: `(.*\={1})\d+(\D*)`

Input: `max. Money (EU)=600000 Euro`

Output: `Euro`

---

This works fine, but it's possible that the Input is like this: `max. Money (EU)=600000 Euro plus 20000 for one person`.

Before the `=` could be anything, the only thing that I know is that the `=` is fixed. So every input have this.

So I'm searching for a regex that will give me for this input this output: `Euro plus for one person`.

I tried to use a regex like `(\D+)`, but I'll get for this input 3 matches. Does someone know how to get all occurences in one match?

Comment: Try [`/=\d+\s*(.*)/`](https://regex101.com/r/hxmPDp/1).

Comment: Thanks, but this will give me the 20000 too.

Comment: Remove it from the match with `preg_replace('~\s*\d+~', '', $m[1])` - see https://ideone.com/8juazv. It is the easiest way since you cannot match discontinuous text with 1 match operation.

Comment: This doesn't look like it needs regex since it looks very static. Could probably split on the `=` and get the space separated values of the second bit.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thank you, would you please post this as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: @apokryfos: It might, but what if there is no number after `=`? Then the `explode` might fetch what is not necessary.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew It's a matter of splitting on `=` and then on " " and filtering by non numeric entries. Regex will probably do more work in the background.

Comment: how about `/=\d+\s*(?=(\S*))/` and get second subsequence?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One cannot match discontinuous text with 1 match operation.

The easiest workaround is to capture the whole substring after `=` + number, and then remove numbers from the match with `preg_replace('~\s*\d+~', '', $m[1])`.

See the [PHP demo](http://ideone.com/8juazv):

```
$re = '/=\d+\s*(.*)/';
$str = 'max. Money (EU)=600000 Euro plus 20000 for one person';
$res = '';
if (preg_match($re, $str, $m)) {
    $res = preg_replace('~\s*\d+~', '', $m[1]);
}
echo $res; // => Euro plus for one person
```

Since you mention that a `=` does not have to be followed by 1+ digits, you may really just `explode` the string at the first `=` and then remove digits in the second item:

```
$chunks = explode("=", $str, 2);
if (count($chunks) == 2) {
    $res = preg_replace('~\s*\d+~', '', $chunks[1]);
}
```

See [this PHP demo](http://ideone.com/MJlVE0).

Comment: I changed the `$re` to `$re = '/=\d*\s*(.*)/';` because there don't have to be a number at the first position after the `=`. Missed to mention that.

Comment: Aha, then you really could use `explode` then. Something [like this](http://ideone.com/MJlVE0).